# Nestjs global cache: CacheInterceptor problem

Tags: nestjs

After configured cache globally like the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching), the CacheInterceptor throws an error if i use it outside the app.module.

app.module.ts

```js
const cacheConfig = {
  store: redisStore,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register(cacheConfig),
    CustomerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: CacheInterceptor
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

customer.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CustomerRepository]), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [CustomerController]
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

customer.controller.ts

```js
@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(CustomerRepository) private customerRepository: CustomerRepository,
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
  async get(): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }, relations: ['customer'] })
    console.log(user.customer.name)
    const customer = await this.customerRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }, select: ['id', 'name'] })
    return { customer: customer.name, email: user.email }
  }
}
```

I would like using the CacheInterceptor along any modules without import the CacheModule each one.

*Nest can't resolve dependencies of the APP_INTERCEPTOR (UUID: 6aa42c77-1bac-4098-b217-1b01eb268240) (?, Reflector). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the CustomerModule context.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `{ provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR, useClass: CacheInterceptor }` you don't need to add in the `@UseInterceptors()` decorator in your `controller`. You should have the `CahceInterceptor` working by default with the rest of the set up

Comment: I have the same error, set the cache module as `global: true`, although I don't want to use `{ provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR, useClass: CacheInterceptor }`  but use `@UseInterceptor(CacheInterceptor )` on some specific endpoints. Any ideas?

Comment: The property is `isGlobal` and it should be set on the top level options for the `register`/`registerAsync`. Without knowing how you configured it, I dunno what to tell you. If it's configured properly, `@UseInterceptor(CacheInterceptor)` should work fine

Comment: I just noticed the `isGlobal` was set within the `useFactory` returned object and not in top level. Thank you!